# What causes (and how can I fix) this odd Core Location error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location

> ERROR,Generic,Time,320195751.128,Function,"void
>   CLClientHandleRegistrationTimerExpiry(__CFRunLoopTimer*,
>   void*)",Registration timer expired,
>   but client is still registering!

There are only a few mentions of this problem that I was able to dig up in the wider Internet, and nobody has useful info. Here's the context:

I have an app that monitors the device's location via CLLocationManager's startUpdatingLocation method. It starts monitoring, runs for a little while, then this message pops up in the debug output. From that point forward, no more location updates are delivered.

This error is killing the location functionality of the app, and I'm at a loss as to what may be causing it. It even has an exclamation point at the end, which means it's clearly an exciting error.

**Update:**
Though I never found a solution to the problem, or figured out why it happens in the first place, I've also lost the ability to reproduce it. This seems to have happened during some period of time in which I did many things, including a general change in code structure followed by update to the iOS 5 beta. Something there seems to have silenced the issue for me.

Comment: I would love to know, too. I've filed a bug with Apple (see [this radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=902401)) but unfortunately it got closed due to "Insufficient Information" because I wasn't able to send them a reproducible case.

Comment: Yeah, the reproducibility is the tough part. I came back the next day, and everything ran fine for awhile. Then it started again. Then it stopped again. I'm not even sure if this is something that will happen outside of a debug build. I don't like the thought that it may occasionally pop up in release builds as well. So far, no luck in tracking it down though.

Comment: What is the desired accuracy and distance? Are you on a WiFi or a 3G?

Comment: Hey Matt are you able to solve this error"Registration timer expired, but client is still registering!". I am getting same error. Can you share your solution with me

Comment: @NavnathMemane, No, I never explicitly solved the issue or determined its cause. It simply ceased occurring for me, so I'm no longer capable of pursuing solutions, or determining if other's solutions are valid.

Comment: OK thanks. I also did not found anything for this...but my app still working fine with this error message

Answer (score 2):

Have you implemented

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

and does this catch it?

You need to check for kCLErrorNetwork, kCLErrorDenied, kCLErrorHeadingFailure and kCLErrorLocationUnknown in the normal run of things but I'm wondering if there are other errors that the delegate can still catch?

This could give you the opportunity to stop and then restart location services.

Comment: Yes, I was sure to handle the failure delegate message, unfortunately it was silent in these situations.

Comment: What about iOS versions and device families? Any idea as to whether it happens more or less on different hardware / iOS versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only a single GSM iPhone 4 to test on, which means I have no information on variations between different hardware. The error only ever showed up sporadically, but I have also not seen it since updating to the iOS 5 beta. I believe I was running 4.2 the last time this happened.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of what @schillace had to share, is it possible that you're attempting to force location updates without heeding the user's authorization status?

Try to hold off on calling `-startUpdatingLocation` until you know that `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the issue. I've been sure to heed the warning in the documentation about the user's ability to stifle the app's locations services at any time, and act accordingly.

Comment: Agreed. I have received the output "Registration timer expired, but client is still registering!" while debugging an app that did have authorisation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer or not, but here's a hint...I'm working with assetFromURL and I'm getting intermittent failures to load images from the asset library. So I wrote a bit of code to test a theory, that loads every url in the library very quickly. I started seeing this error with this bit of code.

So...my theory is that if you make a call that causes the location manager to show the "app wants your location" dialog, and then you **continue to make calls while that dialog is up**, you'll get this error. Once I acknowledged the dialog and re-ran the program, I didn't see this error any more.

Hope that helps, it's just a guess.

Comment: What is "assetFromURL"? I've never heard of it. When I start seeing this error, I'm already well past the authentication stage, so it can't have anything to do with that dialog. Just for fun, I tried resetting all the location warnings, and then assaulting the manager with a variety of messages while the dialog was up... and nothing abnormal happened.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is a problem? It looks to me like you are debugging to a breakpoint (effectively suspending the application) before the registration to the location manager is completed. Meanwhile, the timer expires and you haven't finished your registration. If you take out the breakpoints, does the message ever appear?

Comment: It sure does. I originally noticed this during normal use of the application: no breakpoints enabled. Just reading the plain english of the error does imply that something took too long while attempting to register for location updates, but in practice, the error appears after many location updates are already delivered, which seems to imply that registration succeeded already.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing location stuff on the main thread? I had all sorts of bizarro issues with CLLocation API calls from a background thread. I moved a couple of key setup calls into the main thread, then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and figured out that it was because I had forgotten to mention that the class implements the CLLocationManagerDelegate in the .h file.

Adding the CLLocationManagerDelegate to the header file, and the following line to point to the delegate solved the error for me.

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

Comment: That's interesting that that solved the issue. In my situation, the class has set itself up as the delegate correctly, and also handles the various delegate notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I got this when implementing the timeout (perform selector after delay) in LocateMe, my previous code used another method. I don't know if this is a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add

Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

I did that and the error went away for me.