# Registration timer expired, but client is still registering?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, core-motion

my app program use coremotionmanager and locationmanager too.when i start the program, i found this error.

> ERROR,Time,338977575.221,Function,"void CLClientHandleRegistrationTimerExpiry(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*)",Registration timer expired, but client is still registering!

the error is'nt matter to my program ever. but recently i found my opengles view stopped unexpectedly when i move the ipod touch4 (use gyro).  i checked my project, can't found any error except this.

anyone know how to slove this error.

Comment: Duplicate? There is already some discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098664/what-causes-and-how-can-i-fix-this-odd-core-location-error. Matt Wilding reported that the error was gone after heavy refatoring and installation of iOS 5b. No solution:( Does the error show up always / when you move the device / sometimes / on device only?